# How can I use jQuery to make an element's content the same as another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site with a drop-down menu and I want the titles in it to be the same as the content in an h1 tag on another part of my site

This is my jQuery -

```
const johnName = $("#john").siblings("span");
const johnNameMenu = $(".john").children("h1").val(); 

johnName.html(johnNameMenu);
```

This is the code on my site which I want to appear in the menu -

```
<section class="john">
  <div class="team-header" id="john">
    <div class="teamlogo">
    <img src="images/logos/lazio.png" />
    <h1>John's Team</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="john-roster team-rosters">
    <?php include ('john.php'); ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is the code in the dropdown menu -

```
<a href="#john" id="john-link" class="anchor">
<span></span></a>
```

I want the  "John's Team" to appear in the drop-down menu.

What is wrong with my jQuery code?

Comment: There are no spans in your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the text of an element you use the function `text()`; `val()` is for `<input>` elements.
Note: even though I left the HTML as-is, `id` should be unique in a page.  You should be using class if you want to have multiple of those `<a>` tags in there.

Your selectors and use of .children were not right.  If you still want to use `.children` the line would be `$('.john').children().find('span')`.
I'd recommend using more specific selectors than using `.john (children far down in hierarchy)`.

```js
const johnName = $(".john span");
const johnNameMenu = $(".john h1").text();
console.log(johnNameMenu)
johnName.each(function(){
   $(this).html(johnNameMenu);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is the code on my site which I want to appear in the menu -

<section class="john">
  <div class="team-header" id="john">
    <div class="teamlogo">
    <img src="images/logos/lazio.png" />
    <h1>John's Team</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="john-roster team-rosters">
<a href="#john" id="john-link" class="anchor">
<span></span></a>
<a href="#john" id="john-link" class="anchor">
<span></span></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    const johnName = $("#john").closest("selection").find("span");
    const johnNameMenu = $(".john").children("h1").val(); 

    johnName.html(johnNameMenu);
```